# Pattern of nested functions

Tags: pattern-matching

Suppose I have a list of elements

```
list = {f[b[G[1]]],f[b[1]],k[k[k[G[1]]]]}
```

What is the pattern associated to an expression in which the function `G[1]` appears at the last level of nested functions? For example, I want a `pattern` such that

```
MatchQ[list[[1]],pattern] (*Returns: True*)
MatchQ[list[[2]],pattern] (*Returns: False*)
MatchQ[list[[3]],pattern] (*Returns: True*)
```

In general, this pattern should match an arbitrary expression of nested functions, e.g. `a@b@c@d@e@f@G[1]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
pattern1 = _?({G[1]} == Level[#, {-2}]&);
MatchQ[pattern1]  /@ list
```

> {True, False, True}

Alternatively, define a helper function (`peel`) that strips off heads around `G[1]`:

```
peel = # //. _ @ G[1] -> G[1] &;
```

and define a pattern using `peel`:

```
pattern2 = _?(G[1] == peel[#] &);
MatchQ[pattern2]  /@ list
```

> {True, False, True}

An alternative way to use `peel`:

```
MatchQ[peel @ #, G[1]]& /@ list
```

> {True, False, True}

Comment: What if you want extend the above method for general argument's value of `G`? For example, i want to get the same result for `G[1]` and `G[4]` or with `G[100]`. So.. for any value of the argument.

Comment: @apt45,  does it work if you change the definition of `peel` and `pattern2` as `peel = # //. _ @ G[_] -> G[_] &; pattern2 = _?(G[_] == peel[#] &);`?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to do this using `FoldList`:

```
f = First @@ (Rest@FoldList[Level[#1, {#2}] &, {#}, {Depth[#] - 1}]) &;

MatchQ[f@#, G[1]] & /@ list
```

> {True, False, True}

Answer (score 0):

Use FixedPoint is also a choice.

```
{f[b[G[1]]],f[b[1]],k[k[k[G[1]]]]} //
Map[FixedPoint[Function[expr, expr /. x_[y_[z_]] -> y[z]], #]&] //
Map[# === G[1] &]
```